# Filebeat elasticsearch output with http/https defaults a port 9200

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Here's my `filebeat.yml` setting,

```
output.elastisearch:
  hosts: [ "example.com/something" ]
  protocol: "https"
```

when I look at filebeats logs during runtime, it's trying to reach `example.com:9200/something`

how to skip this default port?

Answer (score 1):

Update the `filebeat.yml` to,

if using `https`,

```
output.elastisearch:
  hosts: [ "example.com:443/something" ]
  protocol: "https"
```

if using `http`,

```
output.elastisearch:
  hosts: [ "example.com:80/something" ]
  protocol: "http"
```